# HTTPS randomly become unresponsive until restart apache

Tags: https, xampp

i have Xampp installed on our Windows 7, and i have been having a problem after changing my os from server 2008 to win 7. My HTTP:// the website works fine, but the HTTPS:// website becomes unresponsive randomly many times in day. It doesn’t load an error page, it just continuously try’s to load the page, then it times out. In Xampp control panel, it doesn’t show any errors, and it says that apache is still running. However, when i stop the Apache and start it back up, the HTTPS:// fixed. What could be going on here? I am using default config.

Comment: Have the same problem and still looking for an answer